# How to introduce diversion in a paper

Tags: phrase-request, style, paraphrasing

In a paper I am writing, there is a large section which diverts from the main topic in order to explain some mathematical concepts. I would like to introduce this section in a sentence such as the following:

*Before we continue, we need to divert in order to explain some mathematical concepts that we will need later on.*

Or:

*In order to continue, we need to make a digression for explaining some mathematical concepts that will be used later.*

Both versions look cumbersome... I am looking for a better way to say this. In particular:

1. Is it better to use "divert", "digress", "make a diversion" or "make a digression" or something else?
2. What preposition comes after the verb - is it "for explaining..." or "in order to explain..." or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure whether diversion is appropriate. I’d better use parenthesis or remark.

Comment: Will any of your readers be already familiar with these concepts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely do **not** want to use *diversion* here. Intransitive use of *divert* is pretty rare, and is usually used for airline flights or other deviations from the planned itinerary of a journey; and *diversion* itself usually means a trivial or entertaining activity.

*We must digress, to explain...* is the simplest way of expressing this meaning; but I suspect it is not really what you want to say. A *digression* is a 'side trip', an exploration of peripheral matters. But your sentence implies that what you have in mind is not peripheral, but central: you are laying the foundation for what follows.

Your *In order to continue* suggests that you have already developed your argument up to a certain point, but now must arrest that argument in order to describe the mathematical concepts you will require to develop the argument further. If that is the case, I suggest saying exactly that:

> Before continuing we must pause to introduce certain mathematical concepts on which our further argument depends.